# Recyclerview in a recyclerview activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-cardview

using firebase-ui and some coding I have set up my code to work like this:
1) it retrieves data from firebase (image, text and so on), then it passes them to another activity.
2) the new activity receives datas like strings and shows them.

Just to give you an idea I am looking forward to building a streaming app. What I want to do is to show an episode list via recyclerview.
What I am doing right now is a nested scroll view and a copy-paste script to pass up to 26 episodes, but this is not a really good method and I would like to have some suggestions in order to go forward in the best way and solve this problem.
this is a screenshot of the app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxCEh.jpg I am just passing strings to the 2nd activity, then i check if it is not a null string, if it is i hide the layout, otherwise it shows, but it is just a copypaste of code. I hope i was clear enough
Thanks everyone for your support

Comment: What are you showing on first activity what are you passing to second activity and how and what are you showing in second activity?

Comment: This question is too broad. Please restrict your issue to a particular programming problem. More infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).